# How to Prevent Collapsing of Kendo Dropdown List on Page Scroll using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am facing a weird issue and tried to implement 3 solutions but it didn't worked out for me.

The problem is with the default functionality of kendo dropdown collapsing on outer page scroll. I want to prevent the collapsing and did some research.

I have got a solution [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/how-to/prevent-close-on-scroll) to prevent this but this is working fine under the **Preview** section shown there but the same is not working under **Dojo (the upper right link)** and in the real project.

There is no difference I can see which prevents the collapsing of Dropdown in **Preview** and not in **Dojo**.

Please, help me resolving the same as I am a newbie in Kendo.

Comment: I suggest you create a post in the Telerik forum. I analysed the preview code and the dojo and it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to handle the **close** event of the widget in order to control this behavior.
Here is an example:

```
 <input id="dropdownlist" />
    <script>
        $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
          dataSource: [ "text1", "text2" ],
          close: _myClose.bind(this)
        });

        var _myClose = function (e) {
            var wish = true;
            var element = e.sender;
            if (wish) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        };
</script>
```

I bind **this** so that you can have the advantage of your class attributes. You can remove it if you want. The kendo widget instance is available under the **e.sender** object.

Here is the link to the [Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-close). 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".k-list-container").each(function () {
    var elementId = this.id.split("-")[0];
    var widget = $("#" + elementId).data("kendoDropDownList");
    if (widget) {
        widget.ul.parent().on("wheel", function (e) {
            var container = this;
            if ((container.scrollTop == 0 && e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) ||
                (container.scrollTop == container.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight && e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this simple snippet to reliably disable page scrolling as long as a kendo dropdownlist is open and the mouse is hovered over the list options.

```
// Fix annoyance where entire page scrolls when you scroll to the bottom of a dropdown
$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var kendoDropdownBoxes = $('.k-list-container[style*="display: block"]');
    if (kendoDropdownBoxes.length > 0 && kendoDropdownBoxes.is(':hover')) {
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    } else {
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
});
```